# Event-driven HTTP client with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, http, events

I have a mobile app with a comment system, backed by App Engine.  When user A replies to user B's comment, user B gets a notification.  Everything works over HTTP.

Right now I have the client device polling App Engine every minute for updates.  It works but on average, there's a 30-second delay before the notification appears.

I would like to close this gap by having App Engine send a packet to user B's device immediately after user A posts the reply.  I can make this happen by moving the `wait(60)` command from the client to the server -- the client will run a tight loop, making another request as soon as it gets a response; App Engine sits on every request for 60 seconds before responding.

But if the user gets a notification, App Engine responds before the 60 seconds are up.  Essentially, user A's request handler wakes up user B's sleeping request handler and causes it to return non-null data.

Is there a name for this technique as applied to HTTP?  Can it be coded efficiently?  If so, how can I implement the wait/notify code?

Comment: You could use xmpp, the transport is http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of sockets App Engine has the Channel API, which should be nearly instant without the need to poll.

[image: Channel API]

[docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/)

Comment: Oh this is perfect!  I _think_ that by nature of HTTP, it has to be implemented as I described above, just wrapped up in a sexy API.